# Using multiple GPU for one dataset at once instead of splitting dataset in tensorflow

Tags: parallel-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I know when training DNN, usual way to use multiple GPU is to split dataset and assign each divided dataset to each GPU.

However, is there a way to use multiple GPU for faster calculation for undivided, whole dataset? I mean when GPU is used for training network, matrix multiplications are parallelized inside the single GPU. Can I make this matrix multiplication faster by using multiple GPU at once?

For example, I have only one picture for dataset. Because I don't have  multiple pictures for splitting and distributing to multiple GPU, I want to utilize all GPUs to contribute for this one picture calculation.

Is it possible in Tensorflow? I've searched in the Internet, but found nothing because it is very rare case.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do something like [model parallelism](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/zh-CN//archive/large_deep_networks_nips2012.pdf). It's a little hacky to do that in tensorflow.

One way to parallelize matmul with two GPU cards. `A X B = C`, `A,B,C` are matrices with shape of `(m,k)`, `(k,n)`, `(m,n)`. 
You can:

1. split `A` to `A1` and `A2` with the shape of `(m/2, k), (m/2, k)`.
2. place `A1` on GPU1 and `A2` on `GPU2`.
3. replicate `B` to both GPU.
4. do computation of `A1 X B = C1` and `A2 X B = C2` concurrently.
5. concatenate `C1` and `C2` to get `C`.

Tensorflow provides operators like [split](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/split), [concanate](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/concat), since B should be replicated on both gpu, you can place B on the [parameter server](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed).